# Send 100 emails with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to notify followers when a discussion changes. A discussion has many followers.
Right now I'm doing this in the Discussion class:

```
self.followers.each do |follower|
    DiscussionMailer.delay.new_reply_notification(user, reply) unless reply.user == user 
end
```

While this is asyncronous, it's pretty slow, memory hungry and creates dependencies on redis and sidekiq.
How can I send the self.followers array to mailgun or another api and send all of the emails like that?
Here's my actual mailer method:

```
  def new_reply_notification(user, reply)
    @user = user
    @reply = reply
    @reply_user = @reply.user

    mail(to: user.email,
         from: "arobot@gmail.com"
         subject: "#{@reply_user.user_name} has just replied!")
  end
```

So I suppose the mail method is key here. How can I change it to do something like this:

```
mail(to: followers_aray,
     from: "arobot@gmail.com"
     subject: "#{@reply_user.user_name} has just replied!")
```

Im up for any gems, the mandrill gem looks promising.

Update

Everyone tells me to do this in a worker. While I agree, ive noticed this field in my smtp logs:

```
"envelope": {
        "targets": "address@gmail.com", 
        "transport": "", 
        "sender": "arobot@gmail.com"
    }
```

So im guessing my envelope can have any number of targets. If my smtp server is doing all the work, why do I need to use a worker?

Comment: if you put all addresses in `to:` everyone will see all email-addresses. probably not want you (or they) want. we usually put an own email-address in the `to:` field and all recipients in `bcc:`.

Comment: Cool... bcc takes an array?

Comment: `to:`, `cc:` and `bcc:` can all take a single address or an array. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail

Comment: So the mail server does the hard work of looping through all the emails? The method takes the same amount of time if its sending to one email or a hundred?

Comment: yes, but i honestly don't know, if there are limits on the mail server itself.

Comment: First thing I would say is not doing this in a controller/model but in a worker. You should constantly check for new messages and send notification to users. Then you can have a similar worker for daily digests, weekly digests, etc.

Answer (score 1):

in your case you should send your emails from a queue using sidekiq or similar this will improve your performance and move it into background job instead of realtime.

After the Discussion been changed push all the followers the the queue and it will send them one by one.

have a look here:

http://sidekiq.org/
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki